# AdSense causing cross-origin read blocking (CORB) warnings in Chrome console log

Tags: google-adsense, google-chrome, cross-origin

I have 1 ad unit and 2 link units of several pages of my site. On these pages, the loading of ads is good. However, when viewing console log in chrome (F12), I am seeing CORB warnings. Interestingly the number of warnings is 3 which corresponds to the total number of AdSense units.

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/ with MIME type `text/html`. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

How can I get rid of this warning?

Comment: according to https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers In most cases, the blocked response should not affect the web page's behavior and the CORB error message can be safely ignored.